# PHP crashing my webpage for unknown reason

Tags: php, mysqli

For some reason, PHP crashes when I try to open a page. I am using `localhost:82` in `Uniform Server Zero`.
The code is as follows:

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';
$db = new DB();
?>
```

core/init.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'localhost:82',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'db' => 'forum'
),
'remember' => array(
    'coolie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user'
)
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once '../functions/sanitize.php';

?>
```

functions/sanitize.php

```
<?php

function escape($string) {   
    return htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

?>
```

I tried adding the text `test` before and after each of the `php` tags, and it seems that only `index.php` crashes (It displays the `test` text before the `php` tags, but not after - even in View Source mode).
The browser I am using is the Aurora dev version, and I am getting the code from [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc) youtube tutorial.

Comment: Consider setting `display_errors` on, in order to locate the problem.

Comment: What is `DB`? Where is it defined?

Comment: as i understood, it comes from autoloader, he registers it in init.php. Answer is still as Ofir Baruch said, just turn on error reporting. :)

Comment: @OfirBaruch OK - I got these errors:
`Warning: require_once(../functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\MyUser\Desktop\UniZ\UniServerZ\www\forum\V2\login\core\init.php on line 25 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='.;D:/MyUser/Desktop/UniZ/UniServerZ/home/us_pear/PEAR') in D:\MyUser\Desktop\UniZ\UniServerZ\www\forum\V2\login\core\init.php on line 25` - lots... and lots... of errors...

I don't know why I got the first error - sanitize.php is there, and I don't know what us_pear/PEAR is...

Comment: Your init.php file is at `login/core/` so `require_once('../functions/sanitize.php')` means that your `sanitize.php` file is at `/login/functions/sanitize.php` , yes?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Yep, it is.

Comment: According to the error it seems that your `include_path` as it set in your `php ini` is "looking" for a different directory.  Read more at (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)